# data lineage on Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metadata, data-lineage

Data lineage is an important factor in data analytics. I could not find any managed or server-less offering in GCP. Is there any offering in road map or is it left to the implementer 
Please enlighten me.

Comment: Please do not create duplicate questions. Instead modify the original question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55000865/8016720.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform data lineage in GCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55000865/how-can-i-perform-data-lineage-in-gcp)